# Validar valores de un array en php

Tags: php, array

Lo que necesito es validar que por lo menos una posición de un array NO SEA NULL. Por ejemplo, tengo un array que contiene criterios de búsquedas, que después de un proceso, se convierte en NULL o con un valor de búsqueda, entonces necesito validar (antes de enviar a procesar) que el array tenga por lo menos 1 valor en alguna posición,  y que no sea todo NULL:

```
    $criterios = array(
    "criterio1" => "",
    "criterio2" => "",
    "criterio3" => "",
    "criterio4" => "",
    "criterio5" => "",
    "criterio6" => "",
    "criterio7" => "",
);
```

Encontré una función para determinar si un valor existe dentro de un array.

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
 echo "Existe Irix";
}
```

Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php

Y también una función que hace búsquedas dentro de un array asociativo.

```
$array = array(0 => 'azul', 1 => 'rojo', 2 => 'verde', 3 => 'rojo');
$clave = array_search('verde', $array); // $clave = 2;
$clave = array_search('rojo', $array);  // $clave = 1;
```

fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php

¿Existe alguna función para esto y de no ser así? cual sería la manera más óptima de validarlo?

Nota: Es indispensable tomar en cuenta "lo de la manera óptima" ya que realmente son muchos criterios de búsqueda y hacer validaciones con "if" sería muy "brusco".

Gracias de antemano. Un abrazo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:( Una disculpa a todos, creo que el cansancio me bloquea. Bueno he descubierto esta posible solución. ¿Alguien me puede recomendar algo mejor?

```
$band=false;
foreach ($criterios as $value) {
    if ($value!==NULL){
        $band = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Viendo que el array son todo string vacíos podrías hacer un  `array_filter()` y luego comprobar si hay algún elemento, además así obtendrás un array solo con las claves que tengan algún valor manteniendo las claves.

Ejemplo:

```
    $criterios = array(
    "criterio1" => "",
    "criterio2" => "",
    "criterio3" => "",
    "criterio4" => "",
    "criterio5" => "",
    "criterio6" => "",
    "criterio7" => "",
);

// Pasamos array_filter y asignamos a $el lo devuelto
// comprobamos con el condicional si el Array esta vacio
if ($el = array_filter($criterios)) {
    echo 'Hay criterios';
    // imprimimos los valores devueltos por array_filter
    print_r($el);
} else {
    echo 'No hay criterios";
}
```

Documentación `array_filter()`: 
http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta es válida y funcional, sin embargo el código que compartí se ajusta adecuadamente a lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de si las cadenas vacías cuentan como "valor", es decir si sólo buscas que no sea todo `NULL`podes usar `implode`, `array_filter` ó `array_filter` con condición.

Te dejo unos ejemplos de cada uno:

- caso 1 : un item tiene valor el resto son cadenas vacías o NULL
- caso 2 : un item es NULL el resto son cadenas vacías
- caso 3 : todos los items son NULL

`arrayEmpty.php`

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$caso1 = array(
   "criterio1" => "",
   "criterio2" => "valor",
   "criterio3" => "",
   "criterio4" => "",
   "criterio5" => NULL,
   "criterio6" => "",
   "criterio7" => "",
);

$caso2 = array(
   "criterio1" => "",
   "criterio2" => "",
   "criterio3" => "",
   "criterio4" => "",
   "criterio5" => NULL,
   "criterio6" => "",
   "criterio7" => "",
);

$caso3 = array(
   "criterio1" => NULL,
   "criterio2" => NULL,
   "criterio3" => NULL,
   "criterio4" => NULL,
   "criterio5" => NULL,
   "criterio6" => NULL,
   "criterio7" => NULL,
);

echo "----------- caso 1".PHP_EOL;
var_dump($caso1);

$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso1));
echo '$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso1)); -> ';
if ($usarImplode) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarImplode.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarImplode.PHP_EOL;
endif;

$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso1));
echo '$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso1)); -> ';
if ($usarFilter) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarFilter.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarFilter.PHP_EOL;
endif;

$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso1, function($val){return $val!==NULL;}));
echo '$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso1, function($val){return $val!==NULL;})); -> ';
if ($usarFilter2) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarFilter2.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarFilter2.PHP_EOL;
endif;

echo "----------- caso 2".PHP_EOL;
var_dump($caso2);

$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso2));
echo '$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso2)); -> ';
if ($usarImplode) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarImplode.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarImplode.PHP_EOL;
endif;

$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso2));
echo '$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso2)); -> ';
if ($usarFilter) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarFilter.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarFilter.PHP_EOL;
endif;

$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso2, function($val){return $val!==NULL;}));
echo '$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso2, function($val){return $val!==NULL;})); -> ';
if ($usarFilter2) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarFilter2.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarFilter2.PHP_EOL;
endif;

echo "----------- caso 3".PHP_EOL;
var_dump($caso3);

$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso3));
echo '$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso3)); -> ';
if ($usarImplode) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarImplode.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarImplode.PHP_EOL;
endif;

$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso3));
echo '$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso3)); -> ';
if ($usarFilter) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarFilter.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarFilter.PHP_EOL;
endif;

$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso3, function($val){return $val!==NULL;}));
echo '$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso3, function($val){return $val!==NULL;})); -> ';
if ($usarFilter2) :
  echo 'SI '.$usarFilter2.PHP_EOL;
  else :
  echo 'NO '.$usarFilter2.PHP_EOL;
endif;
```

los resultados (3 casos, 3 formas de test)

```
$ ./arrayEmpty.php
----------- caso 1
array(7) {
  ["criterio1"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio2"]=>
  string(5) "valor"
  ["criterio3"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio4"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio5"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio6"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio7"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso1)); -> SI 5
$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso1)); -> SI 1
$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso1, function($val){return $val!==NULL;})); -> SI 6
----------- caso 2
array(7) {
  ["criterio1"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio2"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio3"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio4"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio5"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio6"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["criterio7"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso2)); -> NO 0
$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso2)); -> NO 0
$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso2, function($val){return $val!==NULL;})); -> SI 6
----------- caso 3
array(7) {
  ["criterio1"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio2"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio3"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio4"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio5"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio6"]=>
  NULL
  ["criterio7"]=>
  NULL
}
$usarImplode = strlen(implode("",$caso3)); -> NO 0
$usarFilter = count(array_filter($caso3)); -> NO 0
$usarFilter2 = count(array_filter($caso3, function($val){return $val!==NULL;})); -> NO 0
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta es válida y funcional, sin embargo el código que compartí se ajusta adecuadamente a lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.